# How do I add four spaces to the beginning of every line in a selected text via autohotkey?

Tags: regex, string, autohotkey

I'm using the following code at the moment. It works when every line begins with a newline character but not otherwise.
I tried a few variations that result in Autohotkey automatically stripping the beginning of the string.

```
AppsKey::
    oldClipBoard := ClipboardAll ; old Clipboard
    clipboard = ; Emptying clipboard to prepare for ClipWait
    SendInput, ^c ; Copying the selected text (Crtl+C)
    ClipWait

    selected_text := Clipboard

    StringReplace, selected_text , selected_text , `r`n , `n , All

    placeholder := "`n    "
    StringReplace, selected_text , selected_text , `n , %placeholder% , All

    SendInput, %selected_text%

    ClipBoard := oldClipBoard ; restore ClipBoard

    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the four spaces to the beginning of the string to be pasted:

```
SendInput, {space 4}%selected_text%
```

And do not select the line feed or carriage return character(s) at the end of the previous line in your selection.

Note, since a selection of text will not usually start with a newline character the above code merely adds the four characters `{space 4}` to the beginning of the selection and the OP's original code handles the four spaces for each new line (as they do have the preceding newline character which is then replaced by the newline and four spaces).

Comment: I guess you didn't read the OP.  `It works when every line begins with a newline character but not otherwise.` In other words, the OP already had code that added the four spaces at every **new line**, which was accomplished by replacing the newline character `n with the newline character plus four spaces.  Unfortunately that approach neglects the very first line of the original selection (because there is no prior new line character) and the accepted answer (AA) solves that issue.

Comment: I cannot undo the downvote. wtf. since when is that.. if  you edit your post, I can. didn't know that lol. sorry.

Comment: OK -- I'll add further explanation and let's see what happens.

Comment: OK - good to know that editing the post did allow you to undo the DV (at least, it looks like that's what happened).  Thx, I learned something (i.e., the comment above was useful) so I UV'd it.